# Mouse pointer is not moving after upgrading to 16.04

Tags: upgrade, mouse, 16.04

Since I upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04 (coming from 15.10) I experience several issues (System errors after logging in). One of the most annoying of them is that sometimes after system start the mouse pointer is not moving.

Sometimes after some waiting it starts to work properly and it works until the next reboot. Other times it's not moving at all.

The official documentation (https://help.ubuntu.com/16.04/ubuntu-help/mouse-problem-notmoving.html) isn't really helpful. I checked and the mouse is recognised. It also works on other machines as well as on this machine in the BIOS menu or under windows.

Any ideas why this happens or how to fix this?

Comment: Try booting up with an older kernel.

Comment: It looks like the issue is fixed in the meantime. I still get some system errors, but at least the mouse works properly. And thanks for the reply.